# React: Lazy evaluation of Higher Order Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

We're trying to customise the arguments of a HOC (specifically [react-graphql](https://github.com/apollostack/react-apollo)). Due to how this particular library HOC works, we have no ability to influence the component state (queries and options) after the HOC is called.

In a traditional HOC factory like `connect()` in Redux, all contained logic is applied immediately - which is too early for us. Instead, I'm deferring application of the original HOC (`applyOriginalHOC()`) until the construction of the first instance from this component.

```
export function applyLazyHOC(args) {
  return function wrap(WrappedComponent) {
    let ComponentWithLazyHOC; // Closed-over value is scoped to component
    class LazyHOC extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        // Lazy initialising of HOC to give customisations an opportunity to be registered
        if (!ComponentWithLazyHOC) {
          ComponentWithLazyHOC = applyOriginalHOC(
            // Adds customisations which have been registered by third party code
            myCustomization(args)
          )(WrappedComponent);
        }
      }
      render() {
        return <ComponentWithLazyHOC {...this.props} />;
      }
    }

    return LazyHOC;
  };
}
```

It seems like a slightly unconventional approach, so I'm looking for feedback:

- Can you see any side effects of changing the initialisation order of HOCs? I'm assuming HOCs shouldn't rely on the presence of other HOCs.
- Static analysis (e.g. in IDEs) isn't possible with HOCs anyway, so a lazy evaluation doesn't make this any better or worse, right?
- HOCs can provide `context` to React components, which accumulates across nested components - the order shouldn't matter, right?
- A component *definition* never gets unloaded, and `ComponentWithLazyHOC` is only created once per component (not component instance). Can you see any potential for memory leaks?